# Symfony 3 with ldapClient error User Warning: Expected known_string to be a string, NULL given

Tags: php, ldap, symfony

I have an error when authenticating my LDAP
I use fos userbundle
My user is find but when compare password

### My config files :

**`security.yml`**

```
providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    users_ldap:
        ldap:
            service: ldap
            base_dn: "OU=USERS,DC=domain,DC=be"
            search_dn: "CN=ps,OU=apps,DC=domain,DC=be"
            search_password: password
            default_roles: ROLE_USER
            uid_key: sAMAccountName
    chain_provider:
        chain :
            providers: [users_ldap, fos_userbundle]

encoders:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
    AcSecurityBundle\Entity\User: sha512

firewalls:        

    secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/
        anonymous: true
        provider: chain_provider
        form_login:
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            use_referer: true
        form_login_ldap:
            service: ldap
            use_referer: true
        logout: true
```

**`service.yml`**

```
services:
ldap:
    class: 'Symfony\Component\Ldap\LdapClient'
    arguments:
        - ldap.domain.be   # host
        - 636         # port
        - 3           # version
        - true       # SSL
        - false        # TLS
```

### My error :

[image]

What's wrong ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have resolve error message "Expected known_string to be a string, NULL given"

I have replace

Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext

By

Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: bcrypt

But now I search how to dynamically get the user dn 
and bind with it